# Python: is there a difference between using an object as an argument e.g. method(XXX) vs. this syntax: XXX.method()?

Tags: python, syntax, arguments, function-call

Sorry that I do not yet have the vocabulary to express this question properly.

For example:

```
# Import sas7bdat package
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT

# Save file to a DataFrame: df_sas
with SAS7BDAT('sales.sas7bdat') as file:
    df_sas = file.to_data_frame()

# Print head of DataFrame
print(df_sas.head())
```

and

```
# Save file to a DataFrame: df_sas
with SAS7BDAT('sales.sas7bdat') as file:
    df_sas = SAS7BDAT.to_data_frame(file)

# Print head of DataFrame
print(df_sas.head())
```

both produce the same result. Are they generally equivalent or is this a special circumstance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a special case but rather indirect.

You are creating an object `file` that is an instance of that class SAS7BDAT with `with SAS7BDAT('sales.sas7bdat') as file:` and then you are using the Class method `to_data_frame`from the Class instead from the instance directly.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense and provides some vocabulary for me to do some more learning.